# Why Page.User.Identity.Name sometimes show domain part, sometimes doesn't

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I'm building ASP.NET website (not web application) using Windows Authentication.

I use Page.User.Identity.Name to get current login user.

I use TFS for source control:

- in one branch, this expression give me '**DOMAIN_NAME\username**".
- in other branch, it gives me "**username**"

(both branches have same

code).

Do you know what may cause this issue?

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Windows has two classes of user, local users and domain users. Are you accessing the two branches from the same computer at the same time?

Comment: I can only compile and run a code branch at a time in same computer, but the code above produces different results as mentioned in the question.